# grouping of elements of same type together in an array in O(1) Space and O(n) time

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

This is a problem from Elements of programming interviews book.
Question:

> Given an array of *n* objects with keys that takes on of four values, reorder the array so that the objects that have the same type appear together. Use O(1) additional space and O(*n*) time.

I am unable to conceive an idea for more than three groups(Dutch National flag problem). Any help would be really appreciated.

For example a[6]={1,2,3,4,3,1}; Then the result should be {1,1,2,3,3,4} or in any order, only the grouping of numbers matters( ie, the result need not be in ascending order)

Comment: how about running dutch flag once and then the usual quicksort partitioning

Comment: Yeah, I think this will have better time complexity than the answer given below. But is there any way of getting this done in a single pass like the dutch flag solution.

Comment: You (and all answers as of 2022/09/19) take `reorder the array` too literally. Think *fill an array with the same values grouped*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make flag with same color to come together, we could have a pointer variable and swap all those elements that have the current flag to the left and repeat this for each subsequent flag. In the end, we would have all 4 flags grouped together. Space complexity is O(1) and time complexity is O(number of flags * n). Since the flags for your case is 4, it will be O(4 * n) = O(n).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3,3,4};
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int ptr = 0;

    for(int flag=1;flag <= 4;++flag){
        for(int i=ptr;i<size;++i){
            if(a[i] == flag){
                swap(a[i],a[ptr++]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }

}
```

**Update:**

- For `Independent of the number of groups`, you can use a trie data structure. Trie would be composed of binary representation of each number with the last bit node holding the count value of occurrence for that group's element.
- Since we could represent integers in 32 bits, the space occupied by trie would be less and wouldn't grow with respect to the number of groups.
- As a result, space complexity would be O(1). Time complexity would be O(n + log(max_number) * n).

Comment: This looks good and solves the question. But is there any way we can achieve the solution in a single pass like the dutch flag solution. ( Independent of the number of groups)

Comment: @Abishek0398 `Independent of the number of groups` makes this a bit tricky for single pass or two. However, I will give you an update if I arrive with one. Meanwhile, you are free to choose a better answer if you get one :)

Comment: @Abishek0398 I have updated my answer with an idea.

Comment: If you want an idea, run the outer loop until 3: the last group forms automatically (just as the middle one in DNF) and the flag=4 phase just swaps 4-s inside back and forth. The trie idea is not O(1), it builds on using an oversized datatype.

Comment: @tevemadar of course, but it would suffice for the integer range of OP and for most practical purposes. Sure, it does grow if more integer space is accommodated (updated my answer). Also, the idea of a running the loop till flags - 1 does provide an optimization, but time complexity would still remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The O(n) DNF solution forms two sets starting from the lowest and the highest indices, and knows that the third set forming somewhere between them is homogeneous, and thus needs no further treatment.

If you increase the number of sets to four or more, you can still form the top and bottom sets in the same "spirit", and thus in O(n) time, but the middle part remains being mixed, it has to be checked again. And that is why it will not be "pure" O(n) any more - there are only two ends of an array/sequence.

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3,3,4 };
int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

int bottom = 0, top = size - 1;
for (int bottomband = 1, topband = 4; topband > bottomband; bottomband++, topband--) {
    int i = bottom;
    while (i <= top) {
        if (a[i] == bottomband) {
            swap(a[i], a[bottom]);
            i++;
            bottom++;
        }
        else if (a[i] == topband) {
            swap(a[i], a[top]);
            top--;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

You can recognize the "classic" DNF loop inside (when `topband` starts from 3 it simply becomes the original algorithm). `a[]` is taken from the other solution for comparability.

---

There is a thing which is often paraphrased as *The difference between theory and practice is greater in practice than in theory*. Counting the `swap` calls shows that there are 10 of them, which also applies to Vivek's solution. That is part coincidence and part the fact that both solutions are happily swapping identical elements, as only the "current" one is checked, the other one (sitting at `bottom`, `top` or `ptr`) is not. For example the very first thing both algorithms do is to swap the `1` at the beginning of the list with itself.

Via skipping continuous blocks of identical elements (it has to be done both at changing the band and at adjusting the marker), the code grows...

```
int bottom = 0, top = size - 1;
for (int bottomband = 1, topband = 4; topband > bottomband; bottomband++, topband--) {
    while (a[bottom] == bottomband)bottom++;
    while (a[top] == topband)top--;
    int i = bottom;
    while (i <= top) {
        if (a[i] == bottomband) {
            swap(a[i], a[bottom]);
            i++;
            bottom++; // it would be done by the next line in fact
            while (a[bottom] == bottomband)bottom++;
        }
        else if (a[i] == topband) {
            swap(a[i], a[top]);
            top--; // this one too
            while (a[top] == topband)top--;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}
```

...and the number of calls to `swap` decreases to 6. While the complexity class has not changed (I think), the number of actual calls to a potentionally expensive operation has been reduced by 40%. That is the difference between theory and practice.

Answer (score 0):

Let the unik_elems array contain the distinct elements where comparision between then is possible. i.e. we can use `<` or `>` with them. e.g. [1,2,3,4].
so here if these are the 4 distinct elements, then we can choose the pivot at first to be 2 and group 1 on left side of 2, then we change the pivot to 3 and group 2 on left of 3, as we have already grouped 0, we will have the index from when the ungrouped array starts. This way we can then change our pivot to 4. Assumption is that we at first sort the 4 distinct elements that are given to us.

```
nums = [1,4,3,2,2,3,4,1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4,1]
unclassified = 0
unik_elems = [1,2,3,4]
for pivot_idx in range(1, len(unik_elems)):
    pivot = unik_elems[pivot_idx]
# we start the array from the index from where the elements are unclassified.
# Hence, when selecting 3 as pivot in this example, the elements on the left
# of unclassified will be 1 and hence wont we touched when we use 3 as the pivot.
    for idx in range(unclassified, len(nums)):
        if nums[idx] < pivot:
            nums[idx], nums[unclassified] = nums[unclassified], nums[idx]
            unclassified += 1
```

Time Complexity = O(N) and it will be 3 pass solution as we have 4 distinct elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def partition(nums):
    key1_index = 0
    key2_index = 0
    key3_index = 0
    key4_index = len(nums) - 1

    while key3_index <= key4_index:
        if nums[key3_index] == 1:
            nums[key1_index], nums[key3_index] = nums[key3_index], nums[key1_index]
            key1_index += 1
            
            if key2_index < key1_index:
                key2_index += 1

            if nums[key3_index] != 2:
                key3_index += 1
        elif nums[key3_index] == 2:
            nums[key3_index], nums[key2_index] = nums[key2_index], nums[key3_index]
            key2_index += 1
            key3_index += 1
        elif nums[key3_index] == 3:
            key3_index += 1
        else:
            nums[key3_index], nums[key4_index] = nums[key4_index], nums[key3_index]
            key4_index -= 1

    return nums
```

This is a single pass `O(n)` solution that uses `O(1)` space. The basic idea is similar to the case when we have to sort three keys. The first key is an added complexity on top of the usual three-key case. We keep 4 pointers, one for each key. When we encounter an index with a value equal to `key1`, we swap it with the next position where the `key1` is supposed to be inserted. Afterward, we increment `key1_index`. Now, when we increment `key1_index`, it means we also need to increment `key2_index`, but not always. When do we need to increment the `key2_index` after incrementing `key1_index`? When `key2_index` falls behind `key1_index`. For example:

Initial Array: `[3, 1, 1, 2]` # `key1_index = 0` and `key2_index = 0`
After encountering `nums[1] = 1`, we know this needs to go to `key1_index = 0`. So, we put it there and `key1_index` becomes `1`. But now, `key2_index` falls behind. So, we need to increment it also. Otherwise, when we'll encounter `nums[3] = 2`, it will overwrite the first `1` that we just put.

When do we don't need to increment `key2_index`? When `key2_index` has already been incremented and has a bigger value than `key1_index`. In this case, even if we encounter `key1`, it will not impact `key2`'s next insertion place.

We also need to increment `key3`, but not always. When swapping `key1_index` with `key3_index`, we may bring `key2` that was in `key1_index` to the `key3_index` position. For example:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1]
       ^           ^
       |           |
       |  This is where we're currently at, encountering 1.
       |          
This is the position where next 1 (key1) will be inserted


[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
       ^     ^      ^
       |     |      |
       | Next 2 will be inserted here
       |            |
       |            |
       |    We've brought 2 here which need to be put back to their proper 
       |    place (So we can't increment key3. Otherwise, 2 will remain here.)
       |
       |
 1 (key1) has been put into its place
```

If swapping `key3_index` with `key1_index` brings at `key3_index` anything other than `key2`, then we don't need to do anything. Because the sorting order would remain unharmed. Why? Remember that `key4`s are supposed to be inserted from the back of the array. And, if swapping bring a `key3` to `key3_index`, it means there are no `key2`'s in between `key1` and `key3`. So, we don't need to do anything.